# Cursor returns null when an activity is opened for the first time

Tags: java, android, cursor

I have been trying to figure out the problem from past few hours and I am not able to figure out what the exact issue is.

I am creating a WhatsApp sticker app. The cursor returns null when the activity is opened for the first time but returns an exact number of values after another try. Here is the log (this is what I get when I open the EntryActyivty after the fresh install of the app but the error disappears after closing the app)

```
E/EntryActivity: error fetching sticker packs
    android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: After last row.
        at android.database.MatrixCursor.get(MatrixCursor.java:73)
        at android.database.MatrixCursor.getString(MatrixCursor.java:254)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
        at com.ak455.stickermaker.WhatsAppBasedCode.StickerPackLoader.fetchFromContentProvider(StickerPackLoader.java:113)
        at com.ak455.stickermaker.WhatsAppBasedCode.StickerPackLoader.fetchStickerPacks(StickerPackLoader.java:61)
        at com.ak455.stickermaker.WhatsAppBasedCode.EntryActivity$LoadListAsyncTask.doInBackground(EntryActivity.java:98)
        at com.ak455.stickermaker.WhatsAppBasedCode.EntryActivity$LoadListAsyncTask.doInBackground(EntryActivity.java:85)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/EntryActivity: error fetching sticker packs, After last row.
```

Here is my entry activity:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_entry);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.entry_activity_progress);
        loadListAsyncTask = new LoadListAsyncTask(this);
        loadListAsyncTask.execute();
    }

private void showStickerPack(ArrayList<StickerPack> stickerPackList) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (stickerPackList.size() > 1) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, StickerPackListActivity.class);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(StickerPackListActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_LIST_DATA, stickerPackList);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "showStickerPack: Here1");
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, StickerPackDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_UP_BUTTON, false);
        intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_DATA, stickerPackList.get(0));
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
}

private void showErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Log.e("EntryActivity", "error fetching sticker packs, " + errorMessage);
    final TextView errorMessageTV = findViewById(R.id.error_message);
    errorMessageTV.setText(getString(R.string.error_message, errorMessage));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (loadListAsyncTask != null && !loadListAsyncTask.isCancelled()) {
        loadListAsyncTask.cancel(true);
    }
}

static class LoadListAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Pair<String, ArrayList<StickerPack>>> {
    private final WeakReference<EntryActivity> contextWeakReference;

    LoadListAsyncTask(EntryActivity activity) {
        this.contextWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected Pair<String, ArrayList<StickerPack>> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        ArrayList<StickerPack> stickerPackList;
        try {
            final Context context = contextWeakReference.get();
            if (context != null) {
                stickerPackList = StickerPackLoader.fetchStickerPacks(context);
                if (stickerPackList.size() == 0) {
                    return new Pair<>("could not find any packs", null);
                }
                for (StickerPack stickerPack : stickerPackList) {
                    StickerPackValidator.verifyStickerPackValidity(context, stickerPack);
                }
                return new Pair<>(null, stickerPackList);
            } else {
                return new Pair<>("could not fetch sticker packs", null);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("EntryActivity", "error fetching sticker packs", e);
            return new Pair<>(e.getMessage(), null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Pair<String, ArrayList<StickerPack>> stringListPair) {
        final EntryActivity entryActivity = contextWeakReference.get();
        if (entryActivity != null) {
            if (stringListPair.first != null) {
                entryActivity.showErrorMessage(stringListPair.first);
            } else {
                entryActivity.showStickerPack(stringListPair.second);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my fetchStickerPacks method:

```
    public static ArrayList<StickerPack> fetchStickerPacks(Context context) throws IllegalStateException {
            mContext = context;
            final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(StickerContentProvider.AUTHORITY_URI, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("could not fetch from content provider, " + CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY);
            }

            HashSet<String> identifierSet = new HashSet<>();
            final ArrayList<StickerPack> stickerPackList = fetchFromContentProvider(cursor);
            for (StickerPack stickerPack : stickerPackList) {
                if (identifierSet.contains(stickerPack.identifier)) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("sticker pack identifiers should be unique, there are more than one pack with identifier:" + stickerPack.identifier);
                } else {
                    identifierSet.add(stickerPack.identifier);
                }
            }
            if (stickerPackList.isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("There should be at least one sticker pack in the app");
            }
            for (StickerPack stickerPack : stickerPackList) {
                final List<Sticker> stickers = getStickersForPack(context, stickerPack);
                stickerPack.setStickers(stickers);
                StickerPackValidator.verifyStickerPackValidity(context, stickerPack);
            }
            return stickerPackList;
        }
```

And fetchFromContentProvider method:

```
private static ArrayList<StickerPack> fetchFromContentProvider(Cursor cursor) {
        ArrayList<StickerPack> stickerPackList = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.d(TAG, "fetchFromContentProvider: " + cursor.getCount());
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            final String identifier = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(STICKER_PACK_IDENTIFIER_IN_QUERY));
            final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(STICKER_PACK_NAME_IN_QUERY));
            final String publisher = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(STICKER_PACK_PUBLISHER_IN_QUERY));
            final String trayImage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(STICKER_PACK_ICON_IN_QUERY));
            final String androidPlayStoreLink = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ANDROID_APP_DOWNLOAD_LINK_IN_QUERY));
            final String iosAppLink = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(IOS_APP_DOWNLOAD_LINK_IN_QUERY));
            final String publisherEmail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PUBLISHER_EMAIL));
            final String publisherWebsite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PUBLISHER_WEBSITE));
            final String privacyPolicyWebsite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PRIVACY_POLICY_WEBSITE));
            final String licenseAgreementWebsite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LICENSE_AGREENMENT_WEBSITE));

            SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(mContext.getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String psp = mContext.getString(R.string.personal_stickers);
            String from = preferences.getString(mContext.getString(R.string.from), psp);


            final StickerPack stickerPack = new StickerPack(identifier, name, publisher, trayImage, publisherEmail, publisherWebsite, privacyPolicyWebsite, licenseAgreementWebsite);

            stickerPack.setAndroidPlayStoreLink(androidPlayStoreLink);
            stickerPack.setIosAppStoreLink(iosAppLink);
            stickerPackList.add(stickerPack);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        return stickerPackList;
    }
```

Comment: I can't explain why your query is returning an empty cursor.  But you should be checking the result of calling cursor.moveToFirst(). If it returns false, don't execute your do/while loop. That will at least avoid the CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Okay, I will fix it. Thanks!